# Sort CPT archive by order prevents sorting in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, order, menu-order, page-attributes, screen-columns

I've activated the **Order** feature for my 'portfolio' CPT and have managed to arrange my 'portfolio' posts according to respective **Order** values I've provided.

Unfortunately, I've found that this code locks the order that 'portfolio' items are displayed in admin; I can't toggle the **Title** ascending/descending feature nor am I able to sort this list by **Date**.

My goal is to display these 'portfolio' items on the live site using the **Order** feature but I'd still like to be able to make use of the **Title**/**Date** sorting in admin.

```
//add order column to admin listing screen
function add_new_portfolio_column($post_columns) {
    $post_columns['menu_order'] = "Order";
    return $post_columns;
  }
  add_action('manage_edit-portfolio_columns', 'add_new_portfolio_column');


//show custom order column values
function show_order_column($name){
    global $post;
   
    switch ($name) {
      case 'menu_order':
        $order = $post->menu_order;
        echo $order;
        break;
     default:
        break;
     }
  }
  add_action('manage_portfolio_posts_custom_column','show_order_column');


//make column sortable
function order_column_register_sortable($columns){
    $columns['menu_order'] = 'menu_order';
    return $columns;
  }
  add_filter('manage_edit-portfolio_sortable_columns','order_column_register_sortable');


//Sort post archive by menu_order
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mpe_portfolio_sort_order'); 
function mpe_portfolio_sort_order($query){
    if(is_archive() ):
       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
       $query->set( 'orderby', 'menu_order' );
    endif;    
};
```

- I included 'page-attributes' to 'portfolio' CPT 'supports' array.
- 'portfolio' CPT's 'hierarchical' parameter is set to true.
  [image]

Comment: Add an `! is_admin()` check to your `pre_get_posts` function.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `!is_admin()` check to my `pre_get_posts` function. Altered section of code below.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mpe_portfolio_sort_order'); 
function mpe_portfolio_sort_order($query){
    if(is_archive() && ! is_admin() ):
       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
       $query->set( 'orderby', 'menu_order' );
    endif;    
};
```